# Black screen on multi-monitor setup with Shimian QHD display + Apple adapter

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, external-monitor

n00b here with a basic understanding of linux that could ****really**** use some help.

I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04 on my 2018 Razer Blade 15 Advanced with a NVIDIA GTX1060 mobile and I have a dual external monitor setup:

1. Standard Samsung 1080p display
2. Shimian QH270 1440p display

My Samsung monitor is hooked up with a standard native HDMI connection, no complaints there. However, my Shimian display natively uses a dual like DVI connection. Since my laptop doesn't have this port, I purchased an active Apple dual link DVI to mini display port adapter a while back and when I test this adapter on other computers (Windows and Macs) it works perfectly, it even works on my Windows 10 partition without a problem. However with my Ubuntu partition, the Shimian just stays completely blank but is recognized.

I have tried adding resolution modes through `xrandr` but none of the modes stay after I add them so I cant switch to them. I have also tried using a custom edid file (https://github.com/s111/Achieva-Shimian-QH270-EDID) and editing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` to point to it (in multiple different ways) but to no avail. There are very few posts on the Ubuntu+Shimian combo, none of which seem to use a mini display port adapter, and all of which are at least 6 years old for other Ubuntu versions. Even so, I have tried every method on the internet I could find (or so I think) and all of them result in either no change or all my displays going black except for my Samsung monitor (which I am just able to fix by resetting `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`).

I am using the nvidia drivers 510.60.02.

```
mark@markkoszy:~$ xrandr --listmonitors
Monitors: 3
 0: +*HDMI-1-0 1920/609x1080/349+1920+0  HDMI-1-0     // Samsung display
 1: +eDP-1 1920/344x1080/194+0+0  eDP-1               // Built-in laptop display
 2: +DP-1-0 640/169x480/127+3840+298  DP-1-0          // Shimian display
```

Any help would really be awesome, I dont want this great valued monitor to go to waste!

Edit: I also tried `sudo get-edid` but that gave the same black-screen result as above.

Comment: Hello. Not all of these adapters work on all systems. Seems you have one it does not work on. Did the maker say it worked with Ubuntu?

Comment: At system startup, the Linux kernel enumerates all the hardware it can see, and if it "knows" about it, loads a driver module to "handle" the hardware. All of this activity generates log entries. To view all of these logs, to see how the system treated your device,  page through `sudo journalctl  --b  0 -x`.